# Utlizar tags HTML no MarkDown

Tags: html, markdown

Eu testei e funciona, mas, a pergunta é se é uma boa prática. É uma boa prática?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A intenção na origem do Markdown é ser fácil de ler e escrever, prevalecendo essa facilidade de leitura, e é influenciado pelo emails em formato texto.

Depois utiliza-se o Markdown criado para converter para HTML.

Recomendo a leitura dos seus criadores [John Gruber sobre Markdown syntax](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) e [Aaron Swartz sobre Markdown](http://www.aaronsw.com/weblog/001189).

Por isso, acho que o ideal é evitar o HTML e utilizar tanto quanto possível o Markdown original.

No entanto, às vezes é necessário mais coisas que o Mardown original não contempla, como tabelas, e para isso é comum utilizar-se por exemplo o [GFM Markdown - GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/basic-writing-and-formatting-syntax/) ou o [MultiMarkdown](http://fletcherpenney.net/multimarkdown/), entre outras opções.

Espero que isto ajude!